# how to add images to android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, android-gallery, android-mediascanner

any one guide me how to add some images to emulator image gallery?

Answer (score 27):

Goto the DDMS tool in eclipse to push or pull a file onto the emulator. Then go into the running emulator itself, select "Dev Tools" from the Apps screen, select "Media Scanner" (or "Media Provider" in newer versions of Android) to get the emulator to recognize the files so they would be displayed in the Media Gallery.

Comment: There is a bug which crashes Media Provider when one attempts to scan SD card: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62134. Restarting the emulator seems to help the image get recognized.

Comment: MediaProvider crashes.

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to get around it crashing? Restarting the emulator didn't work for me

Answer (score 24):

If you don't care what image this is, it might just be easier to browse to any image on the internet with Android browser, long-tap on it and select "Save image" from the context menu.

Comment: This is crashing the browser for me.

Comment: it is crashing here too

Comment: Works! BUT: See answer from Socialsupaxrew, you have to give storage permission to the browser:  Go to Settings > Apps > Browser > Permission > and allow Storage

Answer (score 12):

Drag image to android emulator and it will transfer image file to download folder. (this only works for genymotion)

Comment: It worked but I had to restart the emulator for the image to appear in the gallery.

Comment: Oh! It was not in my case. Right now i dont have android emulator setup in my machine. Lil busy with iOS

Comment: Needs restart after drag and drop.

Answer (score 6):

Combining a couple solutions here since newer versions of Android crash without the right permissions:

1. Turn on the Storage permission in Settings -> Apps -> Browser -> Permissions to give your emulator browser access to storage.
2. In the emulator Browser app, long press on any image and save it.
3. Saved images now appear in the emulator Gallery app.

Answer (score 5):

To those (Dmitry's answers) that the browser crash when you try to download image from the emulator browser :

You have to authorise the storage to your browser.

Go to Settings > Apps > Browser > Authorisation > and allow Storage

Now you should be able to download any image from this browser.

PS : I would have added a comment to Dmitry's answer but I don't have enough rep

Answer (score 4):

On the off chance someone had this problem: I had issues seeing files I downloaded from browser on API 23 in Android Studio. I've been to four different StackOverflow threads but nothing was helping. I tried Scanning my SD Card from within the Emulator using Dev Tools>Media Provider but it kept crashing.

What finally worked for me was to go to the Downloads app on the Emulator. 
Settings(top right)> Show SD Card. After this I long-click on the image I would like to see in Gallery, Settings > Copy To. Now we have to navigate to the right place in SD Card.

MenuBar(top left) > SDCARD > Android > data > com.android.browser > files > Download  ...finally you should still be within the "Copy To" mode so simply click on Copy (bottom right).

You can also try: MenuBar > Internal Storage > Downloads

Comment: You have to enable "Storage" permission for the Browser app in Settings.  the reason it keep crashing is, That Browser app was not compatible with the new Marshmallow Permission API.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same problem. I wanted to have images in the gallery, so that i could use the Gallery intent to pull in one of those images.

What I did was I set the AVD to have the sim camera, went to the camera app and took a couple pictures. The pics were nothing but the square at different points moving around the frame but it works as examples images.

Its a quick solution to generate images in the gallery if you dont want to bother with the sd card emulation.

Comment: I have the square points moving around as well when selecting a webcam as phone's camera... why is that?

Answer (score 0):

open device settings in android emulator.find `storage>internal storage(shared)>images>download`.

then drag and drop your image file to the download folder.

it will be copied to your AVD internal storage and will show to you.

if it does not showed in your AVD,you have to restart your device.

then you can see the image you copied.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open google browser on emulator and type download free images.
2. You will see options like - unsplash, pexels open website of your wish
3. Then choose an image that you want to download.
4. Click on the download button. it will ask permission. give permission. now your image is downloaded.